# UI appears enlarged when i run build file in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

when i run code in my local the UI components appear normal as how it has to be in reactjs create-react-app.
But when i create build file of the same code and run the build all the UI components appear enlarged.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks and Regards,
Sachin

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sorry, it's impossible to help you with such informations.

It's probably a CSS issue, maybe some CSS rules not applied locally but applied in the bundle build... try to inspect your app with the Browser inspector for checking different CSS rules.

Comment: DOM size has varied provided the css are same. @Luca Fabbri